# How does Unity Remember Specific GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am wondering how unity can remember specific `GameObjects` which has the same name. For example, if I  `Instantiate` like a thousand cubes which has the asme name, `cube(Clone)` and if I ask for a specific cube `Vector3` location, it gives me the `Vector3` correctly. So how does it remembers the cube like using `UUID`?? I just wanted to know so that I can increase my performance

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Object has InstanceID and The instance id of an object is always guaranteed to be unique.
Example

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Create 10 game objects, which will have random Instance IDs
    void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GameObject g = new GameObject("abc" + i.ToString("D3"));
        }
    }

    // Find all the game objects and display their Instance IDs
    void Start()
    {
        Object[] allObjects = Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
        {
            Debug.Log(go + " is an active object " + go.GetInstanceID());
        }
    }
}
```